# The image of a map

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I would like to know if the following is known or where I can find some information to ask the following question.

Let $f\colon M\longrightarrow S^2$ be a non-constant smooth map between smooth manifolds.

I'm wondering how the image of this map can be and if assuming that the dimension of $M$ is large enough I can guarantee that the image of it contains a circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its image need not contain a circle. Here is a cheap construction: First map $M$ surjectively to $[0,1]$ and then compose it with a map $[0,1]\rightarrow S^2$ which does not contain a circle.

BTW: A good question to ask is how many homotopy classes of maps $M\rightarrow S^2$ there are. This has everything to do with the Pontryagin-Thom construction. A good reference is the wonderful book of Milnor: "Topology from the differentiable viewpoint".

Comment: How can justify you always have a smooth map from M onto [0,1]?
Are there no problems with using a manifold with boundary [0,1] in the construction?

Comment: No that does not cause any problems. You can also take $(0,1)$ for example.

Comment: But suppose $M=S^2$, since $M$ is compact you can't have a map from $M$ onto (0,1).

Comment: Of course you can. It can’t be surjective though

Comment: Fair enough, it's true you don't need it to be onto.